# Expected number of families of $5$ children with $3$ boys? at least $4$ boys?

Tags: probability

There are $3,200$ families with $5$ children each. How many of them are expected to have:

a. $3$ boys?

b. at least $4$ boys?

Comment: What is your personal work on this subject ?

Comment: A friend of mine ask my help me to teach him how to solve this problem. I already have my solution (3/5 of the total no. of families). I need help to verify my answer Ma'am @Jean Marie

Comment: Your solution is not correct.

Comment: Do you know bernoulli distribution?

Comment: Do you know *Binomial* distribution ? It is a direct application. The answer to the first question is $\binom {5}{3}\tfrac{1}{2^5}$

Comment: @JeanMarie, that's not the answer yet, it asked for the expected value not the probability, which requires one extra step

Comment: Besides, I am honored by the "Ma'am", but it's not truly appropriate :)

Comment: @Green It *is* the answer: the adjective "expected" shouldn't be taken in connection with "mathematical expectation" here.

Comment: That is I suppose open to different interpretations, to be clear "What *ratio* of them are expected to have..." would result in the probability, where as "What *number* of them are expected to have..." would result in the expected value.  @JeanMarie given that they specify that there are $3200$ families, I would go with the second interpretation because otherwise that information is completely irrelevant and unnecessary to have been included in the problem.

Comment: Additionally the use of *many* makes it seem like they're looking for the number rather than the probability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so you understand better assume that the probability of having a boy is $p$, then that of having a girl is $1-p$. 
Therefore the probability of having 3 boys is
$${{5}\choose{3}} p^3 \cdot (1-p)^{2} $$
Now, multiply this by the number of families to get the answer.
Try to do part b on your own.
As Jean Marie pointed out in the comments, read up on binomial distribution if you didn't get it.

Comment: Thank you Sir Aditya?

Comment: Please, don't call me Sir. Try to solve the second part on your own and comment here if you get the answer. Also, if it helped, accept my solution :)

Comment: Thank you Sir Aditya! Meaning there's no specific answer unless we have a value for p? Can we get the value of p?

Comment: Here, the value of p is obviously 1/2

Comment: For letter b. At least 4 are boys. That is equal to the sum of P(4) and P(5)

Comment: Yes, and multiply that sum to 3200.

Comment: Noted Sir @Aditya. I used P(x) denoting the probability distribution of random variable x.

Comment: Yes Sir Aditya Kumar! Thank you so much and to everyone who help me to understand how I will apply the Binomial Distribution to this problem. Now I can explain it better to my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Events: $A$=having a boy  &  $B$=having a girl.

Assuming when a family gives birth to a child the  P(A) = 1/2
and P(B) = 1/2.50-50 chance

now let's solve (a):
let  X be a random variable that represent number of boys
we first calculate the probability for one family
$P(X=3) = $${5}\choose{3}$$*(1/2)^3*(1-1/2)^2 $

now the the answer is $P(X=3) * 3,200$

the same for (b)

Comment: Kindly use, {N}\choose{k} for binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

let p be probability of having 1 boy child and q be the probability of having 1 girl child

since probability of girls and boys are equal,

therefore

p = 0.5

q = 0.5

P(3 boys and 2 girls) = 5C3 * (p)^3 * (q)^2 = 5C3 * (0.5)^3 * (0.5)^2 = 10/32

P(at least 4 boys) = P(4 boys and 1 girl) + P(5 boys and 0 girl)
= 5C4 * (p)^4 * (q)^1 + 5C5 * (p)^5 * (q)^0
= 5C4 * (0.5)^4 * (0.5)^1 + 5C5 * (0.5)^5 * (0.5)^0
= 5/32 + 1/32
= 6/32

no. of families having 3 boys = P(3 boys and 2 girls) * 3200
= 10/32 * 3200 = 1000

no. of families having at least 4 boys = P(at least 4 boys) * 3200
= 6/32 * 3200 = 600

Comment: Use MathJax to clarify your answer: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference